# How can I simplify a keyframe code

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

Here is my keyframe code. I use for a infinite linear rotation.

```
@-o-keyframes rotating {
   from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
     to { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes rotating {
   from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
     to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Can somehow simplify this code to something smaller?

```
@-o-keyframes rotating, @keyframes rotating {
   from { 
          -o-transform: rotate(0deg); 
          transform: rotate(0deg);}
     to { 
          -o-transform: rotate(360deg); 
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
}
```

Comment: This is more a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The simple answer is...NO, you can't do that. Vendor prefixes cannot be combined into a single setting like that. If a browser encounters a property it doesn't understand it chucks out the whole statement,